# How many authors should attend a conference?

Tags: publications, conference, authorship

I wrote a paper with  3 other students regarding my final year project in mechanical engineering. It was recently selected for a conference in NIT Delhi. Minimum one author is required to present and the price is pretty steep for the participation certificate.Should all of us attend the conference or just one of us? Does the certificate hold any value?

Comment: Poster? Talk? ..

Comment: Currently online conference because of  COVID  otherwise poster if the situation improves by the date for the conference.

Comment: The "certificate" is not the important thing.  Meeting people in your field is the important reason to attend a conference.

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps things are different in India than some other places, but I'd suggest that at least one of you go, as required. The others should make a decision whether the conference, itself, independent of the presentation, has enough value to justify the cost in money and time spent. If any of you intend an academic career, the opportunity to meet others has positive value in building future circles of collaboration.

Note that there may be some discounts for student presenters.

Ii think that, in general, a "certificate of participation" has little value other than as a remembrance.

Of course, if you can draw on a grant for this, the computation changes quite a lot, and then the main cost is the time and effort for the individual. That may not be trivial, of course. Talk too your professor(s).

And, congratulations.

Comment: No, it is mandatory for B.tech to write a paper on the final year work.Also I don't plan to continue any research because I have already accepted a offer from a company.

Comment: I suspect the certificates are required by universities in developing countries for some purpose.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist, possible. Perhaps the OP can enlighten us.

Comment: No certificates are not mandatory for graduating if that's what you were trying to say. Only that you need to be published before actually getting your degree. Also this rule may vary from institute to institute but these days the trend is shifting to promote more students getting their masters in the field of science.

Answer (score 2):

You should pay as little as possible to a conference.  If there is only one presentation, there should only be one paying presenter.

For online conferences, you may be able to submit your presentation as a recording.  The people who appear in the recorded presentation need not be the the paying presenter, unless the conference says otherwise; all the authors could be in the video.  Do follow pandemic quarantine rules.

Comment: "you should pay as little as possible..." ..could you say why?

Comment: @user111388 Because there is no benefit to paying more?  Because you have other uses for money?  I'd say the burden is on the conference to provide a justification for unnecessary payments, and I have never seen such a justification.

Comment: Yes, we decided that only one representative is enough.

Comment: Maybe the payment here refers to the cost of registering / attending, not presenting. So more than one author may wish to attend, even if only one of them is presenting their joint paper.

Comment: No,we were communicated that only people who pay can present the paper.